# Is it possible to build a smartphone app that stream a screen to a TV, while allowing you to remote control it with the phone itself?

Tags: iphone, remote-control

**Is it possible to build an Iphone/Ipad app (and Android app) that can do two things: stream an interface and the respective content (particularly video) to a TV and then let me use the phone itself as a remote control for this interface?**

Basically the idea is, **you don’t need a smart TV anymore or some kind of set-top box or other connected device**, just the smart phone which you carry around all the time anyway and which is connected to your local wireless connection. Maybe a docking station with a HDMR connection to the TV, so you are not emptying your battery.

- Do you know any comparable implementation or use?
- If it is theoretically possible, can you anticipate any performance problems, bottlenecks and how those could be resolved?
- If this it’s not possible, which links are missing, what technology would have to be developed first?

Thank you for your thoughts on this!

Jacob

Comment: Your phone would need an HDMI output.  Some do but most don't.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone/iPad would work for this. It allows you to output to a second screen. You can stream video, audio, whatever. A cool example I saw was using the TV as the primary display and the phone as a controller for a game.

There are two ways to do it. You can use an hdmi output or a vga output. There is also a AirPlay, which will let you do it wirelessly. You would need an AirPlay capable device (like an AppleTV) for it to work though.

Comment: Hi Randall, great this is what I was looking for. Can you remember the name of the game by any chance?

Comment: Found one link myself: http://gigaom.com/apple/video-real-racing-hd-2-now-does-1080p-output-on-ipad-2/

Comment: Regarding the connectors, on Wikipedia is says: "Apple has licensed the audio-streaming portion of the AirPlay protocol stack as a third-party software component technology to other manufacturer partners for them to use in their products in order to be compatible with Apple's iDevices." That's a shame. It's of course anything but ideal to use the Iphone or Ipad as a remote control with a 1 meter long cable connected to the HDMI port of the TV. Is there no alternative to Air Play, if not on iOS, is there one for Android?